# comparing two lists and filter the values

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have these 2 list and I want to identify which of these I don't have in another. But, I have to consider only the substring with number/number, like '2/1'.

list_1:

```
[array([['0/1']], dtype=object), array([['2/1=MV01']], dtype=object), array([['5/2=MV01A']], dtype=object), array([['8/1=MV01B']], dtype=object), array([['9/2=MV01C']], dtype=object), array([['13/2=MV01D']], dtype=object), array([['16/1']], dtype=object), array([['25/1=MV02']], dtype=object), array([['36/1 = MV03']], dtype=object), array([['42/2']], dtype=object), array([['44/2']], dtype=object), array([['46/1 = MV04']], dtype=object), array([['51/2 = MV05']], dtype=object), array([['56/2 = MV06']], dtype=object), array([['58/1 = MV07']], dtype=object), array([['62/2 = MV08']], dtype=object), array([['68/1']], dtype=object), array([['71/2=MV09']], dtype=object), array([['73/1=MV09A']], dtype=object), array([['75/1=MV09B']], dtype=object), array([['76/1=MV09C']], dtype=object), array([['78/2 = MV10']], dtype=object), array([['79/2 = MV11']], dtype=object), array([['81/2']], dtype=object), array([['84/1']], dtype=object)]
```

list_2

```
['2/1=MV01', '9/2=MV01C', '13/2=MV01D', '16/1', '25/1=MV02', '36/1 = MV03', '46/1 = MV04', '51/2 = MV05', '56/2 = MV06', '58/1 = MV07', '62/2 = MV08', '68/1', '71/2=MV09', '73/1=MV09A', '75/1=MV09B', '76/1=MV09C', '78/2 = MV10', '79/2 = MV11', '81/2', '84/1', '5/2', '8/1', '42/2', '44/2']
```

I tried `if not any(str(i) in s for s in Tabela_Dados_Localizados[0]):`

but I think the list_1 isn't getting that right because of the `dtypes` and arrays.

Comment: Is `list_1` a list of multi-dimensional numpy-arrays?

Answer (score 0):

**I hope this helps:**

```
import re

## Make sure list1 and list2 are strings
list1 = "[array([['0/1']], dtype=object), array([['2/1=MV01']], dtype=object), array([['5/2=MV01A']], dtype=object), array([['8/1=MV01B']], dtype=object), array([['9/2=MV01C']], dtype=object), array([['13/2=MV01D']], dtype=object), array([['16/1']], dtype=object), array([['25/1=MV02']], dtype=object), array([['36/1 = MV03']], dtype=object), array([['42/2']], dtype=object), array([['44/2']], dtype=object), array([['46/1 = MV04']], dtype=object), array([['51/2 = MV05']], dtype=object), array([['56/2 = MV06']], dtype=object), array([['58/1 = MV07']], dtype=object), array([['62/2 = MV08']], dtype=object), array([['68/1']], dtype=object), array([['71/2=MV09']], dtype=object), array([['73/1=MV09A']], dtype=object), array([['75/1=MV09B']], dtype=object), array([['76/1=MV09C']], dtype=object), array([['78/2 = MV10']], dtype=object), array([['79/2 = MV11']], dtype=object), array([['81/2']], dtype=object), array([['84/1']], dtype=object)]"
list2 = "['2/1=MV01', '9/2=MV01C', '13/2=MV01D', '16/1', '25/1=MV02', '36/1 = MV03', '46/1 = MV04', '51/2 = MV05', '56/2 = MV06', '58/1 = MV07', '62/2 = MV08', '68/1', '71/2=MV09', '73/1=MV09A', '75/1=MV09B', '76/1=MV09C', '78/2 = MV10', '79/2 = MV11', '81/2', '84/1', '5/2', '8/1', '42/2', '44/2']"


numbers_list_1 = re.findall('(\d{1,2})+(?=\/).(\d{1,2})', list1)
numbers_list_2 = re.findall('(\d{1,2})+(?=\/).(\d{1,2})', list2)

duplicates = []
for a in numbers_list_1:
    for b in numbers_list_2:
        if a == b:
            duplicates.append(a)
            
print(duplicates)
```

**Output:**

```
[('2', '1'), ('5', '2'), ('8', '1'), ('9', '2'), ('13', '2'), ('16', '1'), ('25', '1'), ('36', '1'), ('42', '2'), ('44', '2'), ('46', '1'), ('51', '2'), ('56', '2'), ('58', '1'), ('62', '2'), ('68', '1'), ('71', '2'), ('73', '1'), ('75', '1'), ('76', '1'), ('78', '2'), ('79', '2'), ('81', '2'), ('84', '1')]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some things you don't really explain, like what Tabela_Dados_Localizados is, but I will try to answer this as best as I can.

To see which of the elements of list_2 are included in list_1 you can do:

```
[element in list_1 for element in list_2]
```

which will give a list of True or False of the same length as list_2.

Now, if you only care about the number ratio, you need to isolate that from list_2. Is the format of all the numbers the way you have it there? In so I would first make sure there are no spaces in the elements of list_2:

```
list_2_no_spaces = [element.replace(" ", "") for element in list_2]
```

Then I would split the text on the `=` symbol and keep only what is on the left:

```
list_2_ratio = [element.split("=")[0] for element in list_2_no_spaces]
```

Now, there are two more obstacles. The first is that the numpy elements are saved as objects, but we want strings and the the second is that from what I know numpy does not have a native method to compare substrings element-wise. Instead you can use [numpy.char.find](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.char.find.html#numpy.char.find). The function returns -1 if the substring does not exist in the array. If it does it returns the index. What I would do is:

```
result = [np.any([np.char.find(element_1.astype('str'), element_2) != -1 for element_1 in list_1]) for element_2 in list_2_ratio]
```

The list `result` will have the same elements as list_2 and will be a list of True or False, True if the ratio of the element was found in list_1 and False otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

- first use regex to extract fraction in the list
- use the extracted fraction to test if item in another list
- if matched,use the index `idx` to get original item to show

```py
import re

list1 = [array([['0/1']], dtype=object), array([['2/1=MV01']], dtype=object), array([['5/2=MV01A']], dtype=object), array([['8/1=MV01B']], dtype=object), array([['9/2=MV01C']], dtype=object), array([['13/2=MV01D']], dtype=object), array([['16/1']], dtype=object), array([['25/1=MV02']], dtype=object), array([['36/1 = MV03']], dtype=object), array([['42/2']], dtype=object), array([['44/2']], dtype=object), array([['46/1 = MV04']], dtype=object), array([['51/2 = MV05']], dtype=object), array([['56/2 = MV06']], dtype=object), array([['58/1 = MV07']], dtype=object), array([['62/2 = MV08']], dtype=object), array([['68/1']], dtype=object), array([['71/2=MV09']], dtype=object), array([['73/1=MV09A']], dtype=object), array([['75/1=MV09B']], dtype=object), array([['76/1=MV09C']], dtype=object), array([['78/2 = MV10']], dtype=object), array([['79/2 = MV11']], dtype=object), array([['81/2']], dtype=object), array([['84/1']], dtype=object)]

list2 = ['2/1=MV01', '9/2=MV01C', '13/2=MV01D', '16/1', '25/1=MV02', '36/1 = MV03', '46/1 = MV04', '51/2 = MV05', '56/2 = MV06', '58/1 = MV07', '62/2 = MV08', '68/1', '71/2=MV09', '73/1=MV09A', '75/1=MV09B', '76/1=MV09C', '78/2 = MV10', '79/2 = MV11', '81/2', '84/1', '5/2', '8/1', '42/2', '44/2']
list2

# this step extract only the fraction to list
pattern = re.compile(r'\d+\/\d+')
comp1 = [pattern.match(item[0][0]).group(0) for item in list1]
comp2 = [pattern.match(item).group(0) for item in list2]

list1_notin_list2 = []
list2_notin_list1 = []

#use fraction to compare if list1 all item in list2
for idx in range(len(comp1)):
    item = comp1[idx]
    if item in comp2:
        continue
    list1_notin_list2.append(list1[idx])

for idx in range(len(comp2)):
    item = comp2[idx]
    if item in comp1:
        continue
    list2_notin_list1.append(list2[idx])

print(list1_notin_list2)
print(list2_notin_list1)
```

```
[array([['0/1']], dtype=object)]
[]
```

Answer (score 0):

If we have a `list_1` containing `n` elements and we have to search if each item is in another `list_2` containing `m` elements, it would then be beneficial to create a hash table containing the items of the other `list_2`. This way, we would benefit from the extra `O(m)` operation as all succeeding `n` searches for each item of `list_1` would just be `O(1)`, for a total of `O(n+m)`, unlike if we keep on iterating the the `m` elements of `list_2` to check its equality with each loop of the `n` elements of `list_1`, which will be `O(n*m)`.

We can use [set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) operations for this purpose which provides fast lookups (O(1) for hash tables).

- Also, set provides functionality such as set differences, intersection, etc.

Steps:

- Create a hash table of all `x/y` of `list_2`. The format can be extracted by using regex.
- Iterate each item in the multi-dimensional `list_1`

  - Format the item to `x/y`
  - Search if it doesn't exist in all `x/y` of `list_2`

Code:

```
from numpy import array
import re

def get_num_over_num(value):
    match = re.match(r'\d+/\d+', value)
    if match:
        return match.group(0)
    return None

list_2 = ['2/1=MV01', '9/2=MV01C', '13/2=MV01D', '16/1', '25/1=MV02', '36/1 = MV03', '46/1 = MV04', '51/2 = MV05', '56/2 = MV06', '58/1 = MV07', '62/2 = MV08', '68/1', '71/2=MV09', '73/1=MV09A', '75/1=MV09B', '76/1=MV09C', '78/2 = MV10', '79/2 = MV11', '81/2', '84/1', '5/2', '8/1', '42/2', '44/2']
list_2_num_over_nums = set()
for value in list_2:
    num_over_num = get_num_over_num(value)
    if not num_over_num:
        continue
    list_2_num_over_nums.add(num_over_num)

list_1 = [array([['0/1']], dtype=object), array([['2/1=MV01']], dtype=object), array([['5/2=MV01A']], dtype=object), array([['8/1=MV01B']], dtype=object), array([['9/2=MV01C']], dtype=object), array([['13/2=MV01D']], dtype=object), array([['16/1']], dtype=object), array([['25/1=MV02']], dtype=object), array([['36/1 = MV03']], dtype=object), array([['42/2']], dtype=object), array([['44/2']], dtype=object), array([['46/1 = MV04']], dtype=object), array([['51/2 = MV05']], dtype=object), array([['56/2 = MV06']], dtype=object), array([['58/1 = MV07']], dtype=object), array([['62/2 = MV08']], dtype=object), array([['68/1']], dtype=object), array([['71/2=MV09']], dtype=object), array([['73/1=MV09A']], dtype=object), array([['75/1=MV09B']], dtype=object), array([['76/1=MV09C']], dtype=object), array([['78/2 = MV10']], dtype=object), array([['79/2 = MV11']], dtype=object), array([['81/2']], dtype=object), array([['84/1']], dtype=object)]
list_1_num_over_nums = set()
list_1_num_over_nums_whole = []
for arr_2dim in list_1:
    for arr_1dim in arr_2dim:
        for value in arr_1dim:
            num_over_num = get_num_over_num(value)
            if not num_over_num:
                continue
            list_1_num_over_nums.add(num_over_num)

            # You can also use the whole multi-dimensional array object
            if num_over_num not in list_2_num_over_nums:
                list_1_num_over_nums_whole.append(arr_2dim)

print("Items in list_1 but not in list_2 (whole object):", list_1_num_over_nums_whole)
print("Items in list_1 but not in list_2:", list_1_num_over_nums - list_2_num_over_nums)
print("Items in list_2 but not in list_1:", list_2_num_over_nums - list_1_num_over_nums)
print("Union of items in list_1 and list_2:", list_1_num_over_nums | list_2_num_over_nums)
print("Intersection of items in list_1 and list_2:", list_1_num_over_nums & list_2_num_over_nums)
print("Items in list_1 or list_2 but not in both:", list_1_num_over_nums ^ list_2_num_over_nums)
```

Output:

```
Items in list_1 but not in list_2 (whole object): [array([['0/1']], dtype=object)]
Items in list_1 but not in list_2: {'0/1'}
Items in list_2 but not in list_1: set()
Union of items in list_1 and list_2: {'13/2', '0/1', '56/2', '84/1', '73/1', '75/1', '25/1', '58/1', '81/2', '9/2', '79/2', '36/1', '16/1', '51/2', '42/2', '76/1', '5/2', '71/2', '78/2', '2/1', '8/1', '62/2', '68/1', '46/1', '44/2'}
Intersection of items in list_1 and list_2: {'13/2', '56/2', '84/1', '73/1', '75/1', '25/1', '58/1', '81/2', '9/2', '79/2', '36/1', '16/1', '51/2', '76/1', '42/2', '5/2', '71/2', '78/2', '2/1', '8/1', '62/2', '68/1', '46/1', '44/2'}
Items in list_1 or list_2 but not in both: {'0/1'}
```